# Need to Loop thru a firebaseArray and returning 1 object

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I am trying to access data returned in a firebase array and return 1 of these objects - my firebase array is returning 3 objects and I want to be able to loop through these 3 objects and compare data. Really not sure what to do:

its the function getNewsDetail is the problem.

```
angular.module('news.services', ['ionic', 'firebase' ])
.factory('NewsItems', ['$firebaseArray', function($firebaseArray){
  var newsRef = new Firebase ('https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/newsitems');  

    var theNewsItems = [$firebaseArray(newsRef)];
    //alert($firebaseArray(newsRef).length)
    return{
    getNewsItems: function(){
        return $firebaseArray(newsRef);
    },
    getNewsDetail: function(newsID){
        for(var i = 0; i < theNewsItems.length; i++){
            if(theNewsItems[i].id == parseInt(newsID)){
                return theNewsItems[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    };

}]);
```

Including Firebase layout:

```
      newsitems
          -KIip4vmlntvakLoBAXA
                 Detail: "Detail Y"
                 Title: "Title X"
                 id: 0
          -KIipATckNU1WzEhkY9-
                Detail: "Come down and play with us"
                Title: "New Players Welcome"
                id: 1
          -KIipHiM2NYlh_BgG8UM
               Detail: "story 3"
               Title: "title 3"
               id: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use a single object from Firebase in an AngularJS view, you use `$firebaseObject`. So:

```
getNewsItems: function(){
    return $firebaseArray(newsRef);
},
getNewsDetail: function(newsID){
    return $firebaseObject(newsRef.child(newsID);
}
```

Firebase is intelligent enough in its loading of the data that it won't reload it, if it already has it in memory.

Comment: Thanks Frank I think is close to what I want but not exact - I've added my firebase layout so it probably makes more sense. E.G. if I pass in an id of 2 I would expect the last newsItem on the list to be returned.